# How to add Telerik Report Book into C# Report Libarary

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am using telerik report trial version and would like to club two report into a single report using Report Book feature but unfortunately not able to found option to add it in the C# Report Library.

I have created "Report Book" using telerik standalone designer tool but don't know how do i convert into C# Report library.

I would appreciate if you could give me some advice.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use code behind from book report. You can access by pressing f7 from designer.

An example to club two reports using code behind:

```
    public class ExampleBookReport : Telerik.Reporting.ReportBook
        {
            /* data source to your reports */ 
            public ExampleBookReport (DataSourceModel dataSource)
            {
                /* adding report 1 */
                var instanceReportSource = new InstanceReportSource() { ReportDocument = new ExampleReport1(dataSource) };
                ReportSources.Add(instanceReportSource);

                /* adding report 2 */
                var instanceReportSource2 = new InstanceReportSource() { ReportDocument = new ExampleReport2(dataSource) };
                ReportSources.Add(instanceReportSource2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for response but i am wondering that how do i add Report Book type report in my the report library If I am not wrong it is special kind of book report not normal report.

Comment: The type is ReportBook from Telerik.Reporting namespace (Telerik.Reporting.dll) 

You can add a common report and change that the report inherits from "ReportBook" instead of "Report" in code behind report. 

This article maybe can help you [ReportBook](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-you-create-add-a-report-book)